# JavaScript: Test function

Tags: javascript

I wrote the 'test' function for my 'counter', but it doesn't work! Can you help to understand where I am wrong?

> 'test' must have a method called 'toEqual'!

P.S.: 'counter' is good

```js
function test(data) {
 toEqual: function(e) {
       return (
             this.data.bind(this) == e ? console.log('good'):console.log('sucks!')
        );
 }
}

const counter = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return state + 1;
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return state - 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

test(
    counter(0, { type: 'INCREMENT' })
).toEqual(1);

test(
    counter(1, { type: 'INCREMENT' })
).toEqual(2);

test(
    counter(2, { type: 'DECREMENT' })
).toEqual(1);

test(
    counter(2, { type: 'DECREMENT' })
).toEqual(0);

test(
    counter(1, { type: 'SOMETHING_ELSE' })
).toEqual(1);

test(
    counter(undefined, {})
).toEqual(0);
```

Comment: Your code gives syntax errors!

Comment: You are confusing functions and object literals. A function does not have a method.

Comment: @Bergi - Perhaps I am misunderstanding your comment, but be aware that JavaScript "objects" can most certainly have functions as members.

Comment: Also you cannot access the `data` parameter like a property (`this.`), and the result of calling `counter` is a number so you cannot `bind()` it.

Comment: @DavidW Sure, but the OP is not interested in those (and probably doesn't know about them) so I ignored this detail. He definitely is mixing up the syntax, so that's what needs to be fixed first.

Comment: Fair enough @Bergi :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplification of your code will help to unravel some confusion and resolve the syntax issues you are running into...

Your current `test` function is erroneously written as both an attempt at being a function, and also an object.  Just let `test` be an object (possibly the beginning of a test library), and let `toEqual` be the function (a first function in your test library) that accepts two arguments, like so:

```
    const test = {
      toEqual: function(counterInstance, expected) {
        return counterInstance === expected ? console.log('they are equal') : console.log('they are not equal');
      }
    }
```

Until you have a better grasp of syntax, I would recommend you hold off on the [ES6 arrow function `=>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax. Just write `counter` with the simpler function syntax:

```
    const counter = function(state, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
          return state + 1;
        case 'DECREMENT':
          return state - 1;
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

Then, you can merely call your `toEqual` function with two arguments, like this:

```
    test.toEqual(counter(0, { type: 'INCREMENT' }), 1);
```

Comment: I had answered the same and then saw this **'test' must have a method called 'toEqual'!**

Comment: @Craicerjack - thank you for catching my oversight - answer updated